# Dynamic form validation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, activemodel

I have a form which I want to validate. The validation is based on properties in a couple of other model objects, but the form itself does not correspond to a ActiveRecord model.

Would it be possible to use ActiveModel to achieve this?

```
class Person < ActiveModel
  has_one :shoe
  validates :name, :length => { :maximum => self.shoe.size }
end
```

I basically want to validate a form based on the properties of another model object. Is this possible in anyway?

Comment: unsure what your issue is with ActiveModel/ActiveRecord. what you want is to be able to reference the record in your validation, right?

Comment: I don't have an 'issue' with anything. I just want to do validation in non ActiveRecord model, which is based on the properties of another class.

Comment: but you are showing us an ActiveRecord model. plus the validation has self referring to the person class, but probably meant to refer to the record validated. please clarify

Comment: Sorry, ACtiveRecord was a copy paste error. I am asking if ActiveModel can do this for me, but I am not tied to ActiveModel. I want to perform ActiveRecord style validatation on a class (Person) with the attributes of another class (Shoe), and this class is in turn an attribute of the class being validated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Person 
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  # has_one :shoe # This won't work

  validates :validates_name_length

  private
  def validates_name_length
    errors.add :name, 'too long' if name && name.length > shoe.size 
  end
end
```